# How can I make a PDF when viewed in a browser open links in new tabs?

Tags: php, html, excel, pdf, browser

How can I make a PDF (created by excel) when viewed in a browser open links in new tabs?

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Whether a link to a PDF is opened in a new window or a tab is a browser setting, and not something you can influence from your site. Edit: do you mean links in the site, or in the PDF itself?

Comment: Th is a function of the pdf reader that will is being used by the end user. You don't have control over this.

Comment: Either of you know if it's possible to remove the white space when creating the pdf? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. As far as I know, no browsers really offer any sort of customizability for how users interact with PDFs.